# Remove OR Customize Link in CKEditor Mathjax Plugin

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, mathjax

I am trying to remove / edit the link in CKEditor, have gone through http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-mathJaxClass, couldn't find any properties that allows to customize / edit the link.

[image: MatchJax Plugin for CKEditor]

Answer (score 2):

Edit the dialog file `mathjax.js` under `ckeditor/plugins/mathjax/dialogs/` and remove the documentation element.

This is the part you need to remove or comment out:

```
{
    id: 'documentation',
    type: 'html',
    html:
        '<div style="width:100%;text-align:right;margin:-8px 0 10px">' +
            '<a class="cke_mathjax_doc" href="' + lang.docUrl + '" target="_black" style="cursor:pointer;color:#00B2CE;text-decoration:underline">' +
                lang.docLabel +
            '</a>' +
        '</div>'
},
```

Delete your browser cache before testing.

Answer (score 1):

That link has class `cke_mathjax_doc` so you can set `display:none` in css or change it with jQuery. It's dirty but it should work.